# Purple blisters on my opuntia cactus, need advice

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, cactus

I've had my cactus for a couple years now and it's been doing fine up until a couple weeks ago. It started producing these strange purple blisters where the fuzz comes out. I've been searching everywhere online to find out the cause but with no luck. I'd be very grateful if someone could identify what it happening to my cactus!

For extra context, I live in a very warm place and I try to not water it very often, but sometimes it gets left out to be rained on for several days because I'm not with them to move them out of the way.

[image: cactus]